# Reading data from serial lvds 12bit ADC into Kintex-7 using Xapp524 ref design - corrupted data

Tags: fpga, adc, xilinx

I'm trying to capture ADC data from TI ADS6422 (64xx) using KC705 Board from Xilinx,
I connected the board using FMC-ADC Adapter that connects the ADS6422 EVM board to KC705:
[image]

I did a little research and found out that Xapp524 ref design from Xilinx is the best ref design for serial LVDS ADC deserialization: https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp524-serial-lvds-adc-interface.pdf

I need the ADC to operate in:
12-bit resolution
40 MHz sample rate
2-wire interface
DDR
the Xapp524 documentation states that this is a valid combination.

I connected my pins to the constraints of the design, configured the attributes to my specific ADC needs, and run the ILA debugger.
this is how the data look:
Sampling Frequency: 40 MHz
ILA sample clock: MemClock which is 200MHz from MMCM
Sampled Data: Output data from memory used as a buffer.

Data signal: 5MHz @ -5dBm
run 1:
[image]
run 2:
[image]
run 3:
[image]

Data signal: 8MHz @ -5dBm
run 1:
[image]
run 2:
[image]
run 3:
[image]

As can be seen, the data I get is corrupted, If I'll keep running the samples, I can get even nice looking sine wave, but a sample or two after it, the data is corrupted again.
I tried to look for solutions for this problem, and I found out that because this is an old reference there is a need to do small adaptations like in the ISERDES attributes,
for example, there is 2 ISERDER for each data lane, one for a positive edge and another for a negative edge, so for my understanding, the negative edge ISERDER samples the positive edge - which is wrong, so need to change the attributes:

```
    DYN_CLKDIV_INV_EN   => "FALSE",             -- string
    DYN_CLK_INV_EN      => "FALSE",             -- string
```

to

```
DYN_CLKDIV_INV_EN   => "TRUE",          -- string
DYN_CLK_INV_EN      => "TRUE",          -- string
```

and it may work, but I tried to change it in the negative edge ISERDES of AdcData and FrameData and still the same alignment problem.

The TopLevel schematic:
[image]

Can I have an investigation leads? I'm really stuck here.
Any additional information and code provided for who ask for it,
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try the test pattern from ADC ? That usually helps to find out the nature of data misalignment.